# Recuperando dados com Twitch com JS

Tags: javascript

Alguem poderia me explicar como eu pegou dados dessa API: "https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/streams.md#get-streamschannel". Como por exemplo gostaria de pegar desse usuario: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/beyondthesummit" seu nome, avatar etc. Procurei na internet por alguma explicação mais não encontrei nenhum que explicasse o que eu queria.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Um modo simples é fazendo uma requisição AJAX (no exemplo estou usando jquery), segue um exemplo que retorna um jsonp:

```
$.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "jsonp",
     url : "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/beyondthesummit",
     success: function(data){
       console.log(data);

    }
});
```